# Tools to diff, patch or merge on a word-by-word basis

Tags: merge, latex, diff, markdown, patch

For text, not source code, files like LaTeX, markdown, restructuredText, usually single line breaks does not matter for the semantics and they are frequently refilled within 80 columns. When things are changed, the line break might change by quite a lot. So the common line-by-line diff and patch tools do not actually work for them very well. So I am wondering if there already exist good tools for diffing, patching and even merging this kind of changes? wdiff and git diff --color-words does exactly the kind of thing, but they seem to lack the patching and merging capability. Ideally, if we have got a line

> He do not owe us nothing.

and one author changed it into

> He do not owe us anything.

and another author changed it into

> He does not owe us nothing.

then a merge could give

> He does not owe us anything.

without conflict. That is the ideal result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) can do what you want to have, but from my experience it makes such great diffs that it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you're on a Mac and have installed [XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12), then you can also use the pretty nice app at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app`

Answer (score 0):

Besides meld, you can also use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=de)